# Why is carbon boil even necessary?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, metallurgy

Particularly in an Electric Arc Furnace I have seen carbon boil occuring . I understand the reaction is very vital but what is it's utility? A detailed answer to this is most welcome. The internet says that it promotes slag metal reactions and temperature homogeneity. But my question is how that is it.There are many elements present but why particularly do I need to boing carbon? Why not Si, P etc. This is where the problem seems to be very confusing for me.

Comment: You always ask for a detailed answer, but never proof of any detailed research...

Comment: The internet says that it promotes slag metal reactions and temperature homogeneity. But my question is how that is it.

Comment: Any particular source for that? You should look at your previous questions and think about why they get closed - lack of clarity seems to be the reason. Then improve your questions.

Comment: I edited it slightly.

Comment: I never heard the expression in visiting 50 steel mills around the world. I guess it is some local jargon for oxygen / argon carbon reduction.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Watch this out.I do not get the feeling even after reading this.

Comment: Injecting oxygen burns out carbon as carbon dioxide , it would look like a "boil". I expect it oxidizes P, S, and Si which could make silicate slag .

Comment: @blacksmith37 Got you.Thanks a lot.